# Bulk-loading R-Tree: STR vs OMT vs others

Tags: algorithm, spatial-index, r-tree

I would like to insert many items into R-Tree at once. For that I would like to use "bulk-loading" and I'm in search for performant algorithm. I read about "STR: A Simple and Efficient Algorithm for R-Tree Packing" by Leutenegger, Edgington, Lopez and about "OMT: Overlap Minimizing Top-down Bulk Loading Algorithm for R-Tree".

Please, I have to questions:

- are the more techniques for bulk-loading of R-Trees? Is there any survey of common (and not so common) approaches?
- which is better, STR or OMT? Were there made any comparisons, perhaps someone implemented both could comment on their performance?